# how to print 2D array in TextArea

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, jtextarea

Hello guys I need some help I wanted to print 2D array into a JTextArea with the JButton. I have this method:

```
public static void getMaze(){
    for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
for(int j = 0; j<columns; j++)
    array[i][j] = "[]";

    array [i3][i4]="# ";
    array [i5][i6]="# ";
    array [i7][i8]="# ";
    array [i9][i10]="# ";
    array [i11][i12]="# ";
    array [i13][i14]="# ";

    array [0][0]="S ";         //start
    array [i1-1][i1-1] =" C";  //cil

for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
{
for(int j = 0; j<columns; j++)
{
    System.out.print(array[i][j]+" ");
}
System.out.println("");
}

}
```

where the i3-i14 are random numbers. I tried it with this

```
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++){

                System.out.println(array[i][j]+" ");

     ta1.append(String.valueOf(array[rows][columns]));
    }
            System.out.println("");

        }

            }
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

- You use `array.length` in both iterations (you should use `array[0].length` in one of those cases
- You use `System.out.println` in the "I tried it with this" part of your question. This will result in always printing in a new line.

Did you try whether

```
for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j<columns; j++) {
        System.out.print(array[i][j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

works? Because it seems to do so.

And of course you should insert a newline character in your `ta1` (text area I suppose) when you finish with your inner iteration. `System.out.println` has nothing to do with a textarea it prints to the console.

It is not clear whether you want to write the array to the console or the textarea.